# PSU pop/spark with (0/1) set to 0 (off) and turning power on at wall

Tags: power-supply, gpu, cable, cryptomining

I've just built a mining rig with a GameMax 1350 Watt PSU, 4 rx570 8gb gpus's and 2 rx570 4gb gpus. Each gpu has its own dedicated power line from the psu providing 8+6 pin into the gpu, with 6 PCI-E risers (SATA powered), and an ASRock H81 Pro 2.0 BTC with 24 pin MB power, 12 vault MB power, and 2 4pin molex to support the PCIE. It all works fine, but today I noticed something. I powered the rig down and turned the 0/1 switch on the PSU to off (0), and then switched the system off at the wall. I returned about 3 hours later. With the PSU unit still off (0), I switched the wall socket on. At the power point area I noticed a small spark/flash, and a pop, where the mains input cable goes into the PSU.

Is this normal? If not what could it be. I'm a bit confused because the PSU was definitely at (0) off, so no power should have gone through to the PSU itself.

In other information, when running my rig takes around 4.7amps and 1000 watts when actually mining Ethereum. I noticed the power cable I'm using is 10amps max. Perhaps this needs to be 13amps? It's not a cable specifically designed for that PSU I don't think. It didn't come with it anyway.

I hope I've asked this question at the right stack exchange.

Thanks

Comment: 3 pin power ?  no power cable I have ever seen is 3 pins.  Motherboards are 4 or 8pin.  GPU's 6 or 8.  Floppy disk 4 pin.  All molex connectors 4.  All sata connectors 7.  Fans are 3 or 4 pin, but they usually connector to the motherboard.

Comment: @cybernard To me it sounds like he is meaning the mains input cable, which is going to have a C13 3-pin connector https://i.imgur.com/TY71cZI.jpg

Comment: @cybernard yes that's what I meant. I've updated the question.

Comment: @Mokubai  That could be it, but given how far the plug goes into the PSU, I don't know if you could see a spark that far into the plug.

Comment: @Mokubai it could have been a flash of light seen through the grid vents just next to the power cable in. I'll check the psu power cable requirements if there are any listed.